# Shell command to Get container id from "docker ps"

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am basically looking to achieve this 2 steps:
1. Run the docker image:
   docker run -p 80:80 some-image-name:25
2. Now "docker ps" returns whole data about the container but I was looking for just the container ID to
3. run some test on it.. ex. 
 docker exec -it  /usr/bin/npm run test

So my question is how I can get just the container id from step 2.

Note: I need this flow for my pipeline script in Jenkins.

Comment: What about `docker container ps -q`?

Answer (score 13):

`docker ps -a -q`

This will give you only container's id

Answer (score 6):

You could use awk to get the container ID's as follows:

```
docker ps | awk 'NR > 1 {print $1}'
```

This one-liner outputs all the container ID's printed by docker ps. To get only the first one you would use:

```
docker ps | awk 'NR > 1 {print $1; exit}'
```

Even though that answers your question I recommend that you use [container names](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#:%7E:text=--name,name%20to%20the%20container) instead of relying on container ID's.

P.S.: This solution is on average 1 millisecond slower than `docker ps -q`, but it is significantly more flexible.

Answer (score 4):

```
docker ps --format {{.ID}}
```

Will return only the ids of running containers.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! Sprinkle in `-f | --filter` to get a specific ID.

Answer (score 2):

you can use docker functionality to get this done:

```
docker ps --filter volume=remote-volume --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Mounts}}"
```

with `--format "{{.ID}}"` you'd get the ids only. You can also filter. Read the [documentation of docker ps](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#show-both-running-and-stopped-containers) for more details

Answer (score 2):

### All the below command give you container id's

````
docker ps -aqf "name=containername"

 docker ps --no-trunc -aqf name=containername

docker container ls  | grep 'container-name' | awk '{print $1}'```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can get container ID using following command:

```
docker ps -q
```

Comment: FYI the `awk` command needs to be quoted: `awk '{ print $3 }'`

Comment: question was Get container id from "docker ps"?

Comment: this will get you image id!